# How to use query result in query itself in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to use result value in realm query. I have sqlite query example as below,

```
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from tbl_numbering_plan where np_country_code ='%@' and np_prefix = SUBSTR('%@',0,Length(np_prefix))", [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_CountryCode], [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_CountryCode], [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_Phonenumber]];
```

Here is `tbl_numbering_plan` is table name, `np_country_code` and `np_prefix` are rows of table.

Consider the last part of query that is `np_prefix = SUBSTR('%@',0,Length(np_prefix)`. I want to  make same query in Realm.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you describe what you're querying for and include your Realm objects so we know how they relate. Additionally, you've got 3 parameters for that query and only two placeholders *%@*. Are you querying for a country code as in '1' and then an area code like '555'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your table `tbl_numbering_plan`

Define your models like regular Swift classes

```
class Numbering_plan: Object {
    @objc dynamic var np_country_code = ""
    @objc dynamic var np_prefix = ""
}
```

The last part of query that is `np_prefix = SUBSTR('%@',0,Length(np_prefix)`,

Just handle it as Swift regular `Substring`

```
let dictContactDetails = [String: Any]()
let KEY_CountryCode = "KEY_CountryCode"
let KEY_Phonenumber = "KEY_Phonenumber"
let np_prefix = "np_prefix"
if let code = dictContactDetails[KEY_CountryCode] as? String, var phone = dictContactDetails[KEY_Phonenumber] as? String{
      let index = phone.index(phone.startIndex, offsetBy: np_prefix.count)
      phone = String(phone[..<index])
      let result = realm.objects(Numbering_plan.self).filter("np_country_code = '\(code)' AND np_prefix = '\(phone)'")
      print(result)
}
```

Comment: `let np_prefix = "np_prefix" `, This is not valid, I need value of `np_prefix`, not static string. @dengApro

Comment: Just an example, `np_prefix ` is a `String`, then OK

Comment: Q: If the OP is querying for the country code and prefix, which are two different rows in the table, then they know the country code and prefix they want to query for - what's the purpose of this `let index = phone.index(phone.startIndex, offsetBy: np_prefix.count)` along with `AND np_prefix = '\(phone)'` since they already know the prefix?

Comment: I think the query `NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from tbl_numbering_plan where np_country_code ='%@' and np_prefix = SUBSTR('%@',0,Length(np_prefix))", [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_CountryCode], [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_CountryCode], [dictContactDetails objectForKey:KEY_Phonenumber]];`, is that , u know the code and phone , u are going to fiind out the person or plan fits